# Splitting a 4-dimensional tensor into odd and even lines

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get the odd and even rows of a 4-dimensional input data into a separate variable.

e.g

```
tensor = [[[-1.8391453 ],
           [ 1.9224693 ]],
          [[-0.7931502 ],
           [-0.16963768]]]
```

1. tensorodd= [[[1.8391453],[-0.7931502]]]
2. tensoreven=[[[1.9224693],[-0.16963768]]]

I couldn't convert it for 4 dimensional. and I wasn't sure if what I was doing was right.
I'm not sure what I wrote is correct

This is not exactly what I want. I want to get 1,3,5 rows in a separate variable and 0,2,4,6 rows in a separate variable in the tensor. Actually what I want to do is this:

I want to apply mae formula to tensor. so I want to separate the rows in the tensor and take them as y1 and y2 and apply the formula

[image]

Comment: can you please clarify: what did you expect + what did you actually get

Comment: I reorganized the question.

Comment: So you want to apply MAE to e.g. the pair `[2, 0, 0]` and `[3, 1, 1]`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood what you want to get.

I'm assuming that you have a tensor of shape `(3, 128, 128, 3)` and you want to take:

- The even rows of that tensor, leaving you with a tensor of this shape `(2, 128, 128, 3)`
- The odd rows of that tensor, leaving you with a tensor of this shape `(1, 128, 128, 3)`

Then you could work with indices:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.ones((3, 128, 128, 3)))

# creating a list of indices for 0 axis, in this case [0, 1, 2] 
indices = tf.range(start=0, limit=tf.shape(X)[0], dtype=tf.int32)

# separating the even and odd numbers
even_indices = [x for x in indices if x % 2 == 0]
odd_indices = [x for x in indices if x % 2 != 0]

even_X = tf.gather(X, even_indices)
odd_X = tf.gather(X, odd_indices)

print('Even tensors', even_X.shape)  # prints (2, 128, 128, 3)
print('Odd tensors', odd_X.shape)  # prints (1, 128, 128, 3)
```

---

**Updated** answer after new info:

```
# your input tensor has shape (3, 2, 3)
tensor = tf.constant([[ [0, 0, 0],
                         [1, 0, 0] ],
                       [ [2, 0, 0],
                         [3, 1, 1] ],
                       [[4, 1, 1],
                        [5, 1, 1]]])

even_tensor = [x[0] for x in tensor]
# even_tensor = [<tf.Tensor: [0, 0, 0]>, <tf.Tensor: [2, 0, 0]>, <tf.Tensor: [4, 1, 1]>]

odd_tensor = [x[1] for x in tensor]
# odd_tensor = [<tf.Tensor: [1, 0, 0]>, <tf.Tensor: [3, 1, 1]>, <tf.Tensor: [5, 1, 1]>]

mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
result = mae(even_tensor, odd_tensor).numpy()
```

Instead of working with tensors you can convert to lists, e.g.:

```
odd_tensor = [list(x[1].numpy()) for x in tensor]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is not what I want. I rearranged the question

Comment: thanks. unfortunately this is for 3D. I want to do this for a 4 dimensional tensor. When I do it this way, it returns me a 1-dimensional data. whereas it had to rotate in 2 dimensions.                      vec = tf.random.normal((16, 16, 10, 10))

Comment: But you provided an example for a 3D array. Can you provide the example of a 4D array and expected outcome?

Comment: I don't have an example for now. I am sad. I did it for 3d but I couldn't do it for 4d. I need your help for 4d. thanks

Comment: I updated the example. @ClaudiaR

Comment: I see, however that one is still a 3D tensor. You have to provide an example of a 4D tensor and the desired output that you want to get from that. Otherwise I don't know how to help you.